# gcc-Mingw compilation error on cmd

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw32

i install gcc-mingw on windows 32 bit for c programming languauge .. i install first time in my laptop so when i open notepad file and save this file on desktop with the name of hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 /* my first program in C */
 printf("Hello, World! \n");

 return 0;
}
```

then  when i open command prompt and enter

```
 gcc hello.c -o hello
```

then it shows error

```
gcc:error:hello.c:no such file or directory
gcc:fatal error:no input files
compialtion terminated
```

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your are running the command from a different folder than the one your hello.c file resides

Comment: i just go to start-and write cmd and then enter it